# PhoneGap/Cordova: Google Maps API - drop pin on my position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am able to show my location on a map using Google Maps API in PhoneGap. Right now it just shows the map - no pindrop or anything like that. I was wondering if anyone knew how to drop a pin on the location you bring up?

The code I have so far is:

```
//GEOLOCATION
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
                var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

                //MAP
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                              mapOptions);

            };

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

If anyone can tell me how to drop a pin on that location that would be really awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Adjusted my code:

```
//GEOLOCATION
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
                var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

                //MAP
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                              mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
                                                    map: map,
                                                    title:"Hello World!"
                                                    });

            };

            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            //
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```